# Creating time object from string using date_create_from_format

Tags: php, date, time

I have a `$timeString` formatted as `8:00 PM ET`. I am trying to create a date object using the following:

```
$time = date_create_from_format('g:i A e', $timeString);
```

(source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

When I echo the result using `date("H:i:s", $time)` I am getting `7:00 PM ET`. No matter which time I provide, I always receive 7pm (which is 0:00 GMT).

Am I using the format parameters incorrectly?

Comment: I don't think `ET` is a valid timezone identifier.  Try `EST`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems here.  One is that `ET` is not a valid timezone identifier.  Try using `EST` (or `EDT`).  See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

Second, `date_create_from_format` (or `DateTime::createFromFormat`) returns a `DateTime` object, so you *cannot* use it with the `date()` function.

Your code prints `00:00:00` because `date_create_from_format` failed, so it returned `FALSE`.  `date()` expects the 2nd parameter to be an int, so it "converted" `FALSE` to `0`.  Because of that, you got `00:00:00`.

You need to use the `DateTime` methods to work with a `DateTime` object.  Like this:

```
$timeString = '8:00 PM EST';
$time = date_create_from_format('g:i A e', $timeString);

echo date_format($time, 'H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, once I was using date_format correctly, ET seems to be handled as expected. As you point out, the documentation doesn't mention it. Any ideas why it is working?

Comment: @BenPackard: `ET` doesn't work for me, so no, no idea.

Answer (score 2):

`date_create_from_format()` returns `DateTime object`. whereas `date()` expect 2nd parameter to be a timestamp (int). So you shouldn't use `date()`. Use `DateTime::format()` instead.